# Swift: How to sort a dictionary by value, but the value is a tuple?

Tags: ios, swift

Swift

For example, say I have:

```
var dict = ["a":(3,2), "b":(9,1), "c":(4,3)]
```

I want to sort by the values, but specifically the ***second*** element in the tuple.

I want dict to be below after sorting:

```
["b":(9,1), "a":(3,2), "c":(4,3)]
```

As you can see it's sorted by the second element in the tuple of the value.

I've tried looking everywhere but can't find how to achieve this.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Dictionaries are non-sortable. If you need to sort these elements, you would need to use an array of tuples (or structs). The keys of a dictionary don't have a particular order and you cannot assume it will be the same for the same data.

Comment: I thought they were sortable? You can sort by keys and values.

Comment: No, the dictionary is defined as an unsorted collection (documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary), but you can get sorted representations of it (like in an array or a `String`). Still, the dictionary is not sorted, but its copy to another structure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered and can't be sorted directly but you can sort the content which will give you an array of key value tuples. Then this array can be mapped to an array of keys which can be used to access the dictionary in a sorted fashion.

This will sort by the second value in the tuple and return an array of keys

```
let sorttedKeys = dict.sorted(by: { $0.value.1 < $1.value.1}).map {$0.key}

sorttedKeys.forEach {
    print("\($0): \(dict[$0]!)")
}
```

> b: (9, 1)
>   a: (3, 2)
>   c: (4, 3)

Comment: Thank you, this is literally what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The overload in the standard library is too messy.

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by getComparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try self.sorted(getComparable, <)
  }

  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value, and sorting closure.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    _ getComparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable,
    _ getAreInIncreasingOrder: (Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted {
      try getAreInIncreasingOrder( getComparable($0), getComparable($1) )
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
dict.sorted(by: \.value.1)
```

Comment: This gives a `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` error in `dict.sorted(by: \.value.1)`.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: It does on my Mac, the error is marked on the backslash. Maybe your answer is restricted to specific Swift versions?

Comment: Swift 5.2. Are you using some old version?

Comment: It must be working only on 5.2 then. I tested it in a playground on 5.1 and 4.2 and get that error.